# How can I redirect nohup output to a specified file?

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

Everything I have tried from other examples I have found on SO don't seem to work. I am trying to run my application using nohup but append the output of the application to a file.

I have tried some of the following. None of which seem to work.

```
nohup dotnet application.dll &> out.log &
nohup dotnet application.dll > out.log 2>&1 &
nohup dotnet application.dll > /opt/out.log &
```

I always receive something like

```
-bash: out.log: Permission denied
```

I have tried running the application using sudo but it still doesn't seem to work.

---

```
nohup dotnet application.dll &
```

Works fine, but it directs the output to some other directory like `/home/ubuntu/nohup.out`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `nohup dotnet application.dll > out.log 2>&1 &` should work.

Comment: Apparently you don't have write permissions on that file. Fix that first, then worry about `nohup` and `&`.

Comment: @haccks That's equivalent to OP's first two attempts.

Comment: @melpomene; That's what I said. That should work.

Comment: All the examples should work, though the last one would omit stderr...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`nohup dotnet application.dll > out.log 2>&1 &` is the correct form.

`> out.log` redirects STDOUT to the file `out.log`.

`2>&1` redirects fd2 (STDERR) to fd1 (STDOUT), which is already redirected to the file `out.log`.

Your problem lies in the file permissions (or a read-only filesystem). Prepending `sudo` to your command can't fix this, because only `nohup dotnet application.dll` is executed as root by `sudo`, the output redirection is done by bash with your normal user privileges. You can work around this by calling a separate shell with root privileges:

```
sudo sh -c 'nohup dotnet application.dll > out.log 2>&1 &'
```

Comment: Copy-paste from `man bash`:

There  are  two  formats  for  redirecting standard output and standard error: `&>word` and `>&word`. Of the two forms, the first is preferred. This is semantically equivalent to `>word 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be my file permissions. I assumed that everything would be run as sudo, not just part of it.